# IsPressed Trigger (Button) cause Exception

Tags: wpf, templates, button, triggers, styles

I'm trying to override the button style. 
Actually I've done it dozens of times, but now I came across this:

Exception and InnerException: 
{"A property can not be null in Trigger."}

My Code:

```
<Style x:Key="ArrowRightStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=imgBackground, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      Width="{Binding ElementName=imgBackground, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <Image x:Name="imgBackground" Source="{StaticResource RightArrowImageNormal}" Stretch="None"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="imgBackground" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource RightArrowImageDisabled}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="imgBackground" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource RightArrowImageIsPressed}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

and so it works:

```
    <Style x:Key="ArrowRightStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=imgBackground, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      Width="{Binding ElementName=imgBackground, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <Image x:Name="imgBackground" Source="{StaticResource RightArrowImageNormal}" Stretch="None"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="imgBackground" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource RightArrowImageDisabled}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="imgBackground"
                                Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource RightArrowImageIsPressed}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Why????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from quick look, I think it can't find the property IsPressed

Add "Button." should do it.

```
....
  <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="imgBackground" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource....
```

or make sure that your template targets a button (I know you specified that on the style, but that ain't enough - The template will assume typeof(Control) and control doesn't have IsPressed on it.

```
...
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            ....the rest of your code
```

I think that

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsPressed}"
```

resolves the relative source's type at run time as "Button",hence able to find IsPressed...